# KNN classifier sentiment analysis vs category analysis precision

Tags: machine-learning, sentiment-analysis, document-classification

I have implemented the KNN classifier in java and I got a strange result. If I do a sentiment analysis on a dataset example amazon books review I got 55% precision. From 100 test document 55 correctly classified as negative or positive review and 45 incorrectly. But If I use the KNN for category classification example camera or books then I got 95% precision.

There are some explanation my code is wrong?  Any idea?

Comment: Apples to Oranges? Are you comparing KNN's performance at sentiment analysis and KNN's performance on Categorization? You'd be using radically different features in those cases....it's not the algorithm's fault if those aren't working well....

Comment: @Christopher Pfohl yes, I am comparing KNN performance in categorization and sentiment analysis. What do you mean radically different features? I have used stemming and stopwords.

Comment: thanks @gary, but I need just some theory, my code is huge more than 15 classes, interfaces, I need some theory that it is possible or not.

Comment: Any Machine learning task is highly dependent on the data used, and the features used.  Categorizing and Sentiment analysis are different tasks, so different features will be needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Christopher Pfohl is right. They are different approaches with one key difference for you. Sentiment analysis (based on simple Bag of Words) is much more complicated, in general, than category classification in your case.

Btw, just one clarification, 55% is not precision, that is accuracy.
(More info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accuracy_and_precision#In_binary_classification)

Comment: Thanks for your answer I have used this equation: http://static.usenix.org/event/sec02/full_papers/liao/liao_html/node4.html Can you provide an ecuation for sentiment analysis?

Comment: You should understand the classification process better.

Both processes are classification. However, because the "perspective" you will classify them in is different (sentiment vs category) you need to represent information differently.

Example: For sentiment analysis words like "good" and "bad" are REALLY important, while they are probably noise for topic similarity.

The model is the same, but the representation of the data changes.

Comment: Thank you, I will accept your explanation. Can you provide some source that how I can solve the data representation issue?

Comment: This [paper] (http://es.csiro.au/adcs2009/proceedings/oral-presentation/09-okeefe.pdf) could be a bit complex but it will give you an idea.

This [other paper](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1454712) and [other paper] (http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1361685) will give you more background material :)
I hope this helps